# MYSql Database relationship

Tags: mysql

I want to establish relationship between tables in 2 different databases,

Database1
     table1
     table2

Database2
     table3
     table4

relationship with table1 in database1 with table3 in database2

I want to know is this possible in MySQL?
if yes I have tried within database but i want to know if this is possible

Be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible with the '.' operator.
Lets say you have 2 schema db1 and db2.
table1 is present in db1 and table2 in db2.

So if you want to join the tables, you can::

```
Select * from 
db1.table1 inner join db2.table2 on column1=column2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Foreign key relations can be made as follows while creating table

CREATE TABLE `database1`.`table1`
( `1` INT, 
FOREIGN KEY (`1`) REFERENCES `database2`.`table3`(`1`) ON UPDATE CASCADE );